# Import random time

Tags: python, pyqt4

Python 2.7, pyqt4

I know that

> `Time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()` generates the current time

But how can I get a random hh/mm imported?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you researched, tried, and found to not work?

Comment: What is a "random time"? A number of seconds, a 24 hour time object of some sort, or a random time today or... ?

Comment: @JonClements just a random 24 hour time!

Comment: To what precision... minutes/seconds etc... Have you tried creating a random number between 0 and 24*60*60 for instance and then making that into a time object? Or 3 random numbers: one between 0-23 and two more between 0 and 59 etc...?

Comment: Generate a random number between 0 and 23 (inclusive) for the hours, and a random number between 0 and 59 (inclusive) for the minutes.

Comment: Hmm that sounds good. Hours and minutes, how can I then convert that to a time object?

Comment: @Pythonnewbie start by having a look at the documentation for the `datetime.time` object or the equivalent in QT4?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `qrand()` to generate a random number of seconds:

```
now = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
QtCore.qsrand(now.msec())
time = QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0).addSecs(QtCore.qrand() % (60*60*24))
print(time.toString("hh:mm"))
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this but - NameError: global name ‘qrand’ is not defined

Comment: Hmm still get the same error except now with ‘qsrand’ is not define referencing the second line

Answer (score 0):

There are 60×60×24 seconds in a day, so pick an integer in the range 1 to 86400 and add it to a `QTime` initialised to midnight:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> QtCore.QTime(0, 0).addSecs(randint(1, 86400))
PyQt4.QtCore.QTime(1, 23, 13)
```